# How to run mouse and keyboard events in a minimized window

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am looking for a way to run mouse and keyboard events in a minimized window, simple as that - the code does something in a specific window, while my computer is  free - I can search the web and do whatever; I need Python 2 specifically, but open for 3 suggestions too; This is for automatization of certain tasks I have, I managed to make it work while my computer is in use, but now I need to run it in the background.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22214115/how-to-emulate-mouse-keyboard-events-in-a-unfocused-minimized-window

Comment: Thank you, I am looking into it.